# How can I import my video properly?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, windows

I used a cellphone and it records .3gp I converted to mp4 and When I put it in the video editor it goes wrong

[image: blender]

It seems that it triesa to put it in the computer resolution

Comment: I think it automatically scales the videos to the render canvas' resolution.  If you set it now you may have to look at your clips and change their zoom/scale settings in the N-panel.  It might be easier to set the resolution inside of blender before bringing in the clips.

Answer (score 0):

From version 2.92 on, the scaling problem is resolved. So, I suggest that you upgrade your version. If you want to do it manually, you have to add a transform strip to the .3gp clip and set the scale yourself. You can find the original resolution of the clip in the properties panel under the section Source.

So, if your project resolution is 1920 x 1080 and your .3gp clip is 360 x 740, then your scale Y should be 1080 / 740 = 1.46. This will make the smartphone clip as tall as the project viewport. Of course, you should also scale the Y axis with the same amount (360 x 1.46 = 526 px) to avoid distortion (what you'll have automatically in the previous version), leaving a black bar at each side of the clip.